# Use string variable in Python dataframe function

Tags: python, pandas

If I use

```
df.loc[(origFull['abc'] == 111)]
```

it will work of course.

Then

```
test = '(origFull[\'abc\'] == 111)'

df.loc[@test]
```

or

```
df.loc['@test']
```

Neither worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things are wrong:

1: You want test to be a value(a boolean value to be exact), if you added single quotes around them, `test` turns into a string. Do this instead:

```
test = origFull['abc'] == 111
```

2: `@` symbol isn't valid syntax for python, excepted when it's used for decorators. To use test as a variable, just write `test` without the `@`.

```
df.loc[test]
```

Comment: actually I want test variable to represent a statement, but you are right, I do not need to add single quote. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Take the quotes away when you define test.

Inside of loc you are essentially creating a boolean variable. So set test equal to that boolean and use it as a boolean index:

```
test = (origFull['abc'] == 111)

df.loc[test]
```

Comment: It will work after removing the back slash. Thank you very much, since you are the first one answered this question and brought me to the right direction!

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, just copied and pasted and missed the backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for the [`.query()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method?

```
test = "abc == 111"
df.query(test)
```

Comment: in fact it's .loc, but I got the answer. thanks anyway